# How to set fullscreen on a delphi APP_TYPE GUI

Tags: delphi-xe3, chromium-embedded

another new question, I'm wondering if and how can I get a fullscreen application working on a project that's not using any forms, it's a GUI APP_TYPE.

I am doing SW_MAXIMIZED and border set to none on a form based app which is quite simple,
Any way I can accomplish that on this a cefclient (from Delphi Chromium Embedded):

```
var
{$IFDEF CEF_MULTI_THREADED_MESSAGE_LOOP}
  Msg      : TMsg;
{$ENDIF}
  wndClass : TWndClass;
begin
  //CefCache := 'cache';
  //navigateto := 'client://test/';
  //navigateto := 'local://c:\';


  // multi process
  CefSingleProcess := False;
  if not CefLoadLibDefault then Exit;

  try
    wndClass.style         := CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW;
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc   := @CefWndProc;
    wndClass.cbClsExtra    := 0;
    wndClass.cbWndExtra    := 0;
    wndClass.hInstance     := hInstance;
    wndClass.hIcon         := LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndClass.hCursor       := LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wndClass.hbrBackground := 0;
    wndClass.lpszMenuName  := nil;
    wndClass.lpszClassName := 'tribul';

    RegisterClass(wndClass);

    Window := CreateWindow(
      'tribul',             // window class name
      'Tribul.net - Gods of War',     // window caption
      WS_OVERLAPPED,    // window style
      Integer(0), // initial x position
      Integer(0), // initial y position
      Integer(CW_USEDEFAULT), // initial x size
      Integer(CW_USEDEFAULT), // initial y size
      0,                      // parent window handle
      0,                      // window menu handle
      hInstance,              // program instance handle
      nil);                   // creation parameters

    ShowWindow(Window, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(Window);
```

I don't know if this is the right piece of code where fullscreen part should go but, I tried with SW_MAXIMIZED, not working, and I'm wondering about CW_USEDEFAULT, how can I get an workarea rect so I can set the width and height to overlap the taskbar. or, is it possible ?

Comment: Include `WS_VISIBLE` (`WS_OVERLAPPED or WS_VISIBLE`) to 'window style', set 'initial x position' to `CW_USEDEFAULT`, and 'inital y position' to `SW_MAXIMIZE`. And remove the `ShowWindow` call.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz that works flawlessly so far, but any idea on how to make that top border dissapear too ?

Comment: You mean the caption? If you don't want it, make it a popup window. And also state the maximized flag. I.e. window style = `WS_POPUP or WS_VISIBLE or WS_MAXIMIZE`. In that case you don't have to use `SW_MAXIMIZE` for y.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz if I put that instead WS_VISIBLE and use CW_USEDEFAULT instead SW_MAXIMIZE for y , when I run the App, it shows nothing , (it is in the taskbar but it's like a transparent layer , with nothing on it, preventing me from clicking on anything on the desktop). As I've ran into this a while ago while trying to accomplish this and I don't know what am I doing wrong. It is fullscreen but the "content" is not visible at all, total transparency. http://i.imgur.com/ICC1KJ3.jpg for example

Comment: Would you try providing a brush handle: `wndClass.hbrBackground:=COLOR_BTNFACE+1;`.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Added the brush handle, and it's colouring the whole app , but, the content still not being shown, really wierd. Prinscreen http://i.imgur.com/PS99buZ.png

Comment: As far as I can tell the window looks correct. I can't tell from the code in the question if you have a proper message loop, if you're calling the default window procedure, if your controls are created properly and visible etc..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz http://pastebin.com/PbbGssD4 this is all the code inside the project. It's basically the original cefclient demo from DCEF3 project.

Comment: Dunno, maybe the form is drawing over the 'CustomClient'. If that's the case, including `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` to window styles may help. Otherwise consider adding the 'delphi' tag, someone having chromium-embedded being able to give a test shot may notice the question.